# Almost dysfunctional after training?

Tags: training, pain, stiffness

I recently started training again after a couple months off. I have a good diet with the correct macros for growth and I'm making reasonable progress but I have a problem that after I train I become so weak that I can barely move the body part I've just trained.

For example if I trained Chest and Triceps, when I get into the house if I sit down I can't get back up using my arms and if I lift my arms in the air they drop and then I am unable to re-extend them.

Is there any reason for this and any way I can avoid it?

Comment: Does this happen consistently? And it other muscle groups too?

Comment: @Alec Mainly triceps but legs too. And yeah week in week out, sometimes worse than other times

Comment: @Twyxz This sounds like you are possibly hitting your triceps with too much volume. How many times a week do you train triceps (and chest)? How many exercises per session? How many sets/reps?

Comment: @MadDev Once a week, 4 sets 5-8 reps and 3-5 exercises depending on if I'm fatigued or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is the workout itself. You trained so hard that your muscles 
get very weak for the moment. 
The only way I see to avoid this is to train less. Maybe start by doing one set less on each exercise or even leave one out.
With time you should get used to working out more, which means this feeling of soreness should be less intense after the working, but it depends on your body.

Comment: I'm no longer experiencing muscle soreness the next day it's just after the workout till I sleep I am unable to use my arms etc..

Comment: As I said, try and do less sets or exercises. 99% that should do it. Otherwise, if it really is that bad, I'd go see a doctor.

Comment: will this not affect my muscle gain?

Comment: It depens on your genes of course, but regular exercise and the amount and intensity of the exercise do affect muscle growth. BUT only because you train hard everyday doesn't mean your muscles will grow. Rest is an important factor when trying to gain muscle. If you keep exercising reguarly (even if you leave out some sets or exercises) you will eventually see some gains.

Answer (score 3):

> Once a week, 4 sets 5-8 reps and 3-5 exercises depending on if I'm
>   fatigued or not

If you are doing this on the same day was as when your training your chest, then this is too much volume in a single session. 
Triceps are involved in most compound chest exercises (E.G. Bench Press, Pushups etc.).
So you are probably actually hitting your triceps in 5+ exercises in a single session.

Try changing to max 2/3 exercises which specifically isolate the triceps. (E.G. Cable Tricep Pulldowns, Cable Overhead Extension)

In addition, the 5-8 rep range would be considered a 'strength' rep range. This rep range can be more taxing on the body than your traditonal 'hypertrophy' 8-12 rep range.
But, if your goal is to increase strength, then it's fine to stick to the 5-8 rep range.

Comment: Sorry maybe miscommunication. In total I do 3-5 exercises 4 sets 5-8 reps but this is Chest and Triceps in total. So 3 chest 2 triceps

Comment: Hmm OK then my answer isn't really applicable to your situation. But I'll leave it here just in case it's helpful for somebody else

Comment: linked with Kaiser's answer its still pretty useful